# How to get <mapping resource="com/....."/> in hibernate.config.xml file on eclipse?

Tags: hibernate

I have created hibernate configuration file (hibernate.config.xml) in eclipse. But am not getting the mapping resource `<mapping resource="com/..."/>` in that file. What to do to get it in the hibernate configuration file on eclipse?

Comment: post your hibernate.config.xml

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration><session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://DBname</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
 <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
</session-factory></hibernate-configuration>`

Comment: I didn't get what your problem.Can please tell it clearly

Comment: Actually when I create the hibernate configuration file am getting only the above code. Am not getting <mapping resource=""> lines in hibernate.config.xml.

Comment: I think if you click ctrl+space it not showing you the mapping tag.Is this your problem?

Comment: No. <mapping resource=""> line will be automatically created in hibernate configuration file. rite?

Comment: No.you have to add your mappings in cfg.xml file

Comment: Okay. If I click ctrl+space it not showing the mapping tag.

Comment: Can you please tell where you are trying to add the mapping in your hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: After the line `<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>`

Comment: @Ganesh. The mapping will be automatically created when we generate the reverse engineering file.